# Verify that $x^2 + cy^2 = 1$ is an implicit solution to $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{xy}{x^2 - 1}.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When I differentiate $x^2 + cy^2 = 1$ implicitly and solve for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, I get $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{-x}{cy}.$ I thought I had to multiply by a fraction in order to make it similar to $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{xy}{x^2 - 1}$\$ but nothing worked.
I then checked the answer and someone put up these steps:
\begin{align*}
y^2 &= -(x^2 - 1) * \dfrac{1}{c} \\
y^2 &= c(x^2 - 1) \\
y &= \sqrt{c(x^2 - 1)} \\
y &= c\sqrt{x^2 - 1)}
\end{align*}

I don't get how $\dfrac{1}{c}$ changes to $c$ and it's square root disappears.

Comment: Here,  c  is an arbitrary constant, implies 1/c  is also an arbitrary constant.

Comment: We are just doing these stuff,  to make the solution simple and elegant .You can also stuck with your own c with root like that but that will not hinder the solution. As choice of c is completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that:
$$
x^2 + cy^2 = 1 \iff cy = \frac{1 - x^2}{y}
$$
So:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x}{cy} = \frac{-x}{\left(\frac{1 - x^2}{y} \right)} = \frac{-xy}{1 - x^2} = \frac{xy}{x^2 - 1}
$$

Comment: This seems like it should have been obvious to me. It's definitely better than the answer I was looking at. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac{1}{c}$ is just some constant.
Suppose I want to substitute $k=1/c$
This is what is actually happening here. They take note that $1/c$ is still just some constant and what they did was plug $c$ back in.

This same argument can be used on $\sqrt{c}$

Personally I don't like how the same $c$ was used over and over. How I would prefer to write it is this:
$$y^2 = -(x^2+ 1)*\frac{1}{c_0}$$
Now substitute
$c_1 = \frac{-1}{c_0}$
$$y^2 = c_1(x^2 +1)$$

Hopefully it makes more sense now, and I'll let you continue from here plugging in $c_2 = \sqrt{c_1}$

Comment: That was actually where my thinking was going but I just wanted to make sure. As you said, using 'c' repeatedly is what threw me off. Thanks a lot!